# What does lock icon() on a package under node modules means?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I have built a react Application using create-react-app and using yarn for managing versions. I have noticed some of the packages under `node_modules` directory are with the lock icon. Can someone please help me to understand what does that lock icon indicates? Below is an image for reference.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK this means the user doesn't have ownership to perform CRUD operation on this directory.

Comment: Can you do an `ls -lA` on that directory in addition to that picture? Thanks!